# Get the last day of the current year as date

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format, date-arithmetic

How can I get the last day (Dec 31) of the current year as a date using PHP?

I tried the following but this doesn't work:

```
$year = date('Y');
$yearEnd =  strtotime($year . '-12-31');
```

What I need is a date that looks like 2014-12-31 for the current year.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

PHP `strtotime()` uses the current date/time as a basis (so it will use this current year), and you need `date()` to format:

```
$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Dec 31'));

//or

$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('12/31'));
```

Answer (score 15):

You can just concatenate actual year with required date

```
$year = date('Y') . '-12-31';
echo $year;
//output 2014-12-31
```

Comment: ... or even `date('Y-12-31')`

Comment: I'll go for the second option - thanks a lot for the quick help !

Answer (score 15):

DateTime is perfectly capable of doing this:

```
$endOfYear = new \DateTime('last day of December this year');
```

You can even combine it with more modifiers to get the end of next year:

```
$endOfNextYear = new \DateTime('last day of December this year +1 years');
```

Comment: How can i pass an year as a parameter and get the last day of the year ?

Comment: In that case simply pass the year `$endOfYear = new \DateTime('last day of December 2019');` but bear in mind that this only works for years >1000 as for lower years you will get a 'Failed to parse time string' exception.

Comment: Note that the string "last day of December this year" can be useful to use with the `modify()` function.

Comment: To get the last day of last year use `"last day of december last year"`

Answer (score 5):

Another way to do this is use the Relative Formats of `strtotime()`

```
$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december this year'));

// or

$yearEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last day of december'));
```