# how to get last day of year from given date?

Tags: php

Anyone can give me a solution to ?
I want to get last date of year base on given date not the last day of the current year

Ex:

```
$date2 = '2014-03-17';

$date1 = '2015-01-02';

$date = '2016-08-17';
```

I want to get this:

```
$date2 = '2014-12-31';

$date1 = '2015-12-31';

$date = '2016-12-31';
```

Comment: take the year and add `-12-31` should be easy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: best way to get the last day of the current year as date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976813/php-best-way-to-get-the-last-day-of-the-current-year-as-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Last day of December", strtotime($date)));
```

Comment: That will be the same as `echo date("Y-12-31", strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 2):

try this,
use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
   function lastday($dateValue)
   {    
    $time=strtotime($dateValue);
    $year=date("Y",$time);
    $currentY = date('Y');
    $lastyearE = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 31,  $year );
    return  date('Y-m-d',$lastyearE);
   }

   $dateValue1 = '2016-08-17';
   $dateValue2 = '2015-01-02';
   $dateValue3 = '2016-08-17';
   echo lastday($dateValue1);// pass your date in function
   echo lastday($dateValue2);
   echo lastday($dateValue3);
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/HgSCc)**

i hope it will be helpful.